# How to localize new 'posts' with ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, dynamic-data

Im just starting with localization today and need some information.

I have a project running in ASP.net MVC using .resx (global / local) files to place text based on the chosen language on the page. But this is premade/static content. How to do this for, for instance, new posts if you have a blog? Do you have to do it by loading different partial pages like in [localizing asp.net views and master pages][1] ? What is common? Can not think of a decent google-term to find information on this.

I have no idea what the normal procedure would be, so any information on this topic would be lovely.

[1]: http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/09/30/manager.html localizing for asp.net views and master pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the actual content to be localized you can use 3 approaches:

1. Write them in different languages and add a field in the database with the language of the post. Filter the posts in the controller according the current lang.
2. Use an automatic translate service to do the translation ([Google API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxlanguage/) - [Microsoft API](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/Dev/Ajax/))
3. Leave the post in the original languages and add a translate widget to the site (like [this site](http://www.istartedsomething.com/))